# Kibana including versioned documents in visualizations

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch

I have a document with `_id` "123456", and when I do a GET in Elasticsearch for that ID in my index I can see that it is `_version: 2` which makes sense because I updated it.

However in my Kibana visualizations it seems like it is picking up both versions of the same document when showing the results.

How do I exclude versioned documents from re-appearing in the visualization? For example, this record is showing up twice in my bar graph.

Please and thank you

---

Example GET response:

```
{
    "_index": "censored",
    "_type": "censored",
    "_id": "123456",
    "_version": 2,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        ... ommitted
    }
}
```

Also I am sure there is only one actual document with that ID because if I do a `_search` on the `_id` field I can see this:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 7.53924,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "censored",
                "_type": "censored",
                "_id": "123456",
                "_score": 7.53924,
                "_source": {
                    ... ommitted
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Things I've tried below**

```
aggs": {
    "latest": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id"
      }
    }
}
```

and

```
"aggs": {
    "latest": {
      "max": {
        "field": "version"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So frankly this is just a workaround, if someone finds a better solution I will mark that as the answer instead. Anyway this is how I've been able to prevent multiple records with the same `_id` showing up in my visualizations on my dashboard:

I just changed the `"Y Axis - Count"` on all the visualizations to being `"Y Axis - Unique Count on field _id"`

Honestly it seems silly that I have to do this because I think different versions should just automatically be exempt from appearing in my saved searches & visualizations. I couldn't find any information about why this was happening. I even tried a `_forcemerge` to try and delete previous versions of records but it didn't do anything.

Would be nice if someone found a real solution.